# Reverter edição de título

Tags: debate

Tópico em questão:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/93593/revisions

Eu discordo da edição do título dessa pergunta. O título original era simples e intuitivo.

O novo título é mais extenso e apresenta uma sutil ambiguidade.

"Como receber valores passados via POST normal através de um método JavaScript"

A ambiguidade é que dá a entender que o resgate do POST é por um método JavaScript. Isso descaracteriza muito a versão original pois a questão é bem clara tanto no título original quanto no contexto.

Acho que também dizer "POST normal" é desnecessário. O método POST é um só. Não tem POST normal ou POST "anormal".. rsrsr

O título original era "PHP não consegue ler variáveis passadas por JavaScript".

As edições no conteúdo estão ótimas. Parabéns pela paciência de quem fez, mas o título está ruim.

Comment: Os editores são notificados se você fizer um comentário `@NomeDoEditor`.  Não entendo porque não vai lá e acerta o título você mesmo... (?)

Comment: Se você discorda do título novo, e consegue identificar um problema que pode ser resolvido, basta editar novamente

Comment: parece simples fazer o óbvio.. e foi por isso que abri essa discussão, afim de evitar algum desentendimento. Quem editou tem pontuação equivalente a minha e achei que seria invasivo ou desrespeitoso remover a edição dele. E também posso estar equivocado quanto a minha interpretação. Se outros enxergam uma posição contrária ou favorável, seria interessante para chegarmos a uma conclusão.

Comment: [Ajustei lá](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/93593/revisions), se achar que pode melhorar, não se acanhe :)

Comment: @brasofilo, deu na mesma. rsrs .. o ponto principal é a ambiguidade.

Comment: voltei o original e troquei "variáveis" por "POST".

Comment: Perfect! Obrigado por remover a ambiguidade!